# Update SFDC's Date field from Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, servicecloud, object

A journey with entry source as Salesforce data, needs to update the Salesforce record's field with TODAYs date. How to achieve this from OBJECT ACTIVITY update or any approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Event "Object Activity" in the Journey, select your object and action (likely find and update), and in step "Map Fields", find the relevant Date field. Then you will have the option to select:

"Date Contact Enters Activity"

This should be the current date.